# LateX making text look like the url command

Tags: latex

So I want the formatting of the url command, but not specifically to be an URL. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the formatting of the URL command:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

Regular \url{website} text.

\end{document}
```

To achieve the same output, use

```
Regular \texttt{website} text.
```

or

```
Regular {\ttfamily website} text.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you'd want to look it like a URL without attaching a URL. You can do this with: `\href{run:}{text}`.

**Executable Example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\href{run:}{This is my URL like text}
\end{document}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]